# How to add My documents shortcut to the right-hand column on the start menu?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, start-menu

How do I add "My documents" (or other folder shortcuts) to the right column (grey-tinted) on the start menu in Windows 7?

Comment: don't understand what you meant, please screenshoot and show us.

Answer (score 3):

Simply right click on the empty space and select properties:

[image]

Then select "Customize..."

[image]

Then choose the options you want to be displayed, and how you wish to interact with them.

[image]

and Voila! Documents have been added. Alas, you cannot add custom shortcuts, just the options provided in this list.

Comment: Well, what if I want to add a folder?

Comment: You can't. you are limited to just the items on this list.

However, whenever you right click a folder you have an option to "Pin to start".

This will add it to the LEFT column (the white one) which you can manipulate accordingly.